# Generating Serializer from Golang Struct

Tags: go, struct

I have a struct like this,

```
type Example struct{
    a int
    b int
    c string
}

func Calculate(){
    obj := Example{1,2,"lahmacun"}
    // do something in here
    // I have to get this result as a string: "[a=1,b=2,c=lahmacun]"
    // Example can be anything. which means we dont know anything about struct. Just we know its a struct.
}
```

I want to make a serializer but i could not make it.

Note : In nodejs we have for...in loop. It was very easy. But in golang everything very different to me.

Comment: Why don't you just marshal it to JSON text? You have support for that in the standard library: `encoding/json`. Also note that generally you need to export fields of structs for other packages to be able to access them (e.g. name them `A`, `B` and `C`).

Comment: Make struct variables `A,B,C` exportable and marshal it to json

Comment: To loop over the fields of an arbitrary struct you can use the `reflect` package, using that you can then create the desired string (`"[a=1,b=2,c=lahmacun]"`).

Comment: @mkopriva i was try this reflect package but its not working with type (or i could'nt make it right)

Comment: @icza i am trying to do that right now .

Comment: i got the json. But now i have only json text. I have to loop it but how ? Is json can loop with fields ?

Comment: @FurkanAydın here's an incomplete example https://play.golang.org/p/dkU-lzayphm; to go this route you need better handling of possibly invalid values and other field types etc.

Comment: If you really wants to loop the struct. So use `reflect` package and loop through the struct

Comment: @mkopriva i love you <3 Thank you :) <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a answer. Thanks to @mkopriva <3

```
func PKIStringify(v interface{}) (res string) {
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    num := rv.NumField()
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        fv := rv.Field(i)
        st := rv.Type().Field(i)
        fmt.Println(fv.Kind())
        res += st.Name + "="
        switch fv.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            res += fv.String()
        case reflect.Int:
            res += fmt.Sprint(fv.Int())
        case reflect.Struct:
            res += PKIStringify(fv.Interface())
        }
        if i != num-1 {
            res += ","
        }
    }

    return "[" + res + "]"
}
```

Comment: What if a field value contains a `,`, `=`, or `]`?

Comment: @Adrian nice question :) i gess i have to change these to unicode or something. I dont know right now. i have to think about this :)